# How to record a live stream video using java swing

Tags: java, video, stream, recording

I want to know that is it possible to record and save alive stream using Java swing satndalone application.If so please provide with some example.

Think a stream URL is mms://192.168.2.1:7700 , and i want to save the video along with playing.Help is appreciated accordingly.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I tried with vlcj,JMF but not succeded .

Comment: It is better if you suggest me how to approach this also..

Comment: *"It is better if you.."* ..hire a tutor.  Voting to close.

Comment: @BachiJava did you succeed in this?